# show logout only if user is not logged in

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a php script for the navigation bar. This is what I have but it keeps showing a blank page, if I remove the links and put a redirect instead it works without any problems.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) { 
    echo "<a href='create.php'>Create</a>"
    echo "<a href='search.php'>Search</a>"    
} else {
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>"
    echo "<a href='create.php'>Create</a>"
    echo "<a href='search.php'>Search</a>"
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing all the semicolons

```
echo "<a href='create.php'>Create</a>"; <---
echo "<a href='search.php'>Search</a>"; <----

}
 else {
    echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>"; <---
    echo "<a href='create.php'>Create</a>"; <---
    echo "<a href='search.php'>Search</a>"; <---
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot semicolons `;` after every `echo`.

If you had placed `error_reporting(-1);` after your opening php tag you would have seen errors.